# Stretched Tabs with Netbeans 7.1 and Synthetica

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel

I need to set the system property "winsys.stretching_view_tabs=true" in a Netbeans 7.1 application with the Synthetica LAF. 
Does someone have a clue where exactly I need to put this property in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that all required steps about how to integrate `Synthetica, Themes and SyntheticaAddons in your Netbeans Platform application (RCP)` are on  [Official Pages by Jyloo Software](http://www.javasoft.de/news/)

Comment: Yes, except for this little detail. Infact, their website is where I got the info about this switch, but they don´t specify *where* it is to be set in. I tried the LAF installer class and several .properties files in org/netbeans/core/*, to no avail.

Comment: then [apply Laf directly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html), this is direct way without instaling, set plugins...whatever,

Comment: I don´t think this is relevant, I probably didn´t describe my problem accurately. The LAF is actually applied, this switch is not for Synthetica, it´s a Netbeans-fix because they changed the look of group tabs in 7.1. I.e i would have to place this switch even if i didn´t use Synthetica.

Comment: @Jannis Alexakis sorry I never used plugins to the Netbeans, I used those features directly